# No data received in push notification

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I'm using the following java code to send a push notification to gcm. The google server or whatever response ok HTTP code200 ,with the appropiate multicast_id  and message_id. The problem: when I try to get data of pushevent.data on my browser,  when the `notification arrives..there´s nothing on it. No data, zero.
 Why? The devtools shows : PushEvent :data {null}. 
The push notification appears perfectly .But I want to show data from server to browser , Is this possible?? 
So sorry of my English

This is the code on the server:

```
public void method(){
 try {
 String apiKey = "AIzaSyB74usn5bPOiPi57DqC3mlaQHvIv5AEoWc"; 
        //API key provided by Google Console    
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.findByTelefono("600112207");
        String deviceID = usuario.getRegistrationId();
        System.out.println(deviceID);               
        Content content = new Content();
        //POJO class as above for standard message format
        content.addRegId(deviceID);       
        content.createData("Mensaje para el usuario:",usuario.getUsuario());
        URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+apiKey);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        mapper.writeValue(wr, content);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



//the Content class
package antia.PFC.utils;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Content implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4598819886093518574L;
public List<String> registration_ids;
public Map<String, String> data;
public void addRegId(String regId) {
    if (registration_ids == null)
        registration_ids = new LinkedList<String>();
    registration_ids.add(regId);
}
public void createData(String title, String message) {
    if (data == null)
        data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("title", title);
    data.put("message", message);

}
}

//the service-worker.js




//Version 0.1
'use strict';

console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
self.skipWaiting();
console.log('Installed', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
console.log('Activated', event);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
console.log('Push message', event);
if (event.data) { 
console.log('Push message',event.data.json())
}
var title = 'Mensaxe Quendas';
event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title,{
body : 'Ten vostede unha solicitude de cambio',
tag :'my-tag',
}));
});
```

Comment: Can you also post your manifest file in the question?

Comment: {
  "name" : "Push Notifications codelab",
  "gcm_sender_id" : "267438983609"

}

Comment: I´ve been reading this:  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption   Maybe it's mandatory to encrypt the data or payload.